# Preprocessing with gixsql adds uncompilable gnucobol code

Tags: preprocessor, cobol, gnucobol

I recently started using gixsql for a project I am working on.
https://github.com/mridoni/gix/blob/main/doc/gixsql.md

I followed the examples in the readme, but when compiling with GnuCobol the sample TEST001.cbsql is not working:

```
TEST001.cbsql: in paragraph 'GIXSQL-CI-P-TEST001-EMPTBL':
TEST001.cbsql:394: error: syntax error, unexpected Identifier
TEST001.cbsql: in paragraph '100-EXIT':
TEST001.cbsql:383: error: 'GIX-SKIP-CRSR-INIT' is not defined
```

If I remove this generated code then the program compiles, although it removes an important section from the program and does not work properly. Just wondering what I might be doing wrong? I am following the example using GnuCobol to compile the preprocessed cobol to connect to a PostGres database.

```
cobc -x TEST001.cbsql -L /opt/gixsql/lib -lgixsql
```

Here is the generated section that is causing the compile issue:

```
GIXSQL*
GIXSQL*   ESQL CURSOR DECLARATIONS (START)
GIXSQL     GO TO GIX-SKIP-CRSR-INIT.
GIXSQL GIXSQL-CI-P-TEST001-EMPTBL.
GIXSQL     CALL STATIC "GIXSQLCursorDeclare" USING
GIXSQL         BY REFERENCE SQLCA
GIXSQL         BY REFERENCE x"00"
GIXSQL         BY VALUE 0
GIXSQL         BY REFERENCE "TEST001_EMPTBL" & x"00"
GIXSQL         BY VALUE 0
GIXSQL         BY REFERENCE SQ0001
GIXSQL         BY VALUE 0
GIXSQL     END-CALL
GIXSQL GIX-SKIP-CRSR-INIT.
GIXSQL*
GIXSQL*   ESQL CURSOR DECLARATIONS (END)
```

Original cbl file is from the gixsql examples

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       
       PROGRAM-ID. TEST001. 
       
       
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION. 
       
       CONFIGURATION SECTION. 
       SOURCE-COMPUTER. IBM-AT. 
       OBJECT-COMPUTER. IBM-AT. 
       
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION. 
       FILE-CONTROL. 
       
       DATA DIVISION.  
       
       FILE SECTION.  
       
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. 
       
       EXEC SQL 
        INCLUDE EMPREC 
       END-EXEC. 
       
           01 DBNAME PIC X(64).
           01 DBAUTH PIC X(64).
           01 T1     PIC 9(3) VALUE 0.  
           01 DISP-RATE PIC 9(15). 
           01 DISP-COM PIC 9(3).  
           01 DISP-CODE PIC 9(8). 
           01 FAKE-CHAR PIC X.  
           01 ANSS PIC X. 
           01 COM-NULL-IND PIC S9(4) COMP. 
           
           01 VARC PIC X(20).
           01 VARD PIC X(20).
       
       EXEC SQL 
            INCLUDE SQLCA 
       END-EXEC. 
      *  declare cursor for select 
           EXEC SQL
               DECLARE EMPTBL CURSOR FOR
               SELECT                     
                    ENO,
                    LNAME,
                    FNAME,
                    STREET,
                    CITY,
                    ST,
                    ZIP,
                    DEPT,
                    PAYRATE,
                    COM,
                    MISCDATA
                 FROM EMPTABLE
               ORDER BY LNAME
           END-EXEC              
       PROCEDURE DIVISION. 
 
       000-CONNECT.
         DISPLAY "DBNAME" UPON ENVIRONMENT-NAME.
         ACCEPT DBNAME FROM ENVIRONMENT-VALUE.
         DISPLAY "DBAUTH" UPON ENVIRONMENT-NAME.
         ACCEPT DBAUTH FROM ENVIRONMENT-VALUE.
         
      *   DISPLAY '***************************************'.
      *   DISPLAY " DB  : " DBNAME.
      *   DISPLAY " USER: " DBAUTH.
      *   DISPLAY '***************************************'.

           EXEC SQL
              CONNECT TO :DBNAME USER :DBAUTH
           END-EXEC.      
           
           IF SQLCODE <> 0 THEN
              DISPLAY 'SQLCODE. ' SQLCODE
              DISPLAY 'SQLERRM. ' SQLERRM
              GO TO 100-EXIT
           END-IF.
       100-MAIN.

           EXEC SQL
              START TRANSACTION
           END-EXEC.                                                    
       
      *  open cursor
           EXEC SQL
               OPEN EMPTBL
           END-EXEC 
           MOVE SQLCODE TO DISP-CODE
           DISPLAY 'open ' DISP-CODE.
           DISPLAY 'open ' SQLERRM.
       
      *  fetch a data item 
           EXEC SQL
               FETCH EMPTBL INTO 
                 :ENO,:LNAME,:FNAME,:STREET,:CITY, 
                 :ST,:ZIP,:DEPT,:PAYRATE, 
                 :COM,:MISCDATA
           END-EXEC. 
       
       100-test. 
           MOVE SQLCODE TO DISP-CODE
           DISPLAY 'fetch ' DISP-CODE
       
      *  loop until no more data
           PERFORM UNTIL SQLCODE < 0 OR SQLCODE = 100
       
      *  display the record
           MOVE PAYRATE TO DISP-RATE
           MOVE COM TO DISP-COM
           DISPLAY 'employee #: [' ENO ']'
           
           DISPLAY 'last name : [' LNAME ']'
           DISPLAY 'first name: [' FNAME ']'
           DISPLAY 'street    : [' STREET ']'
           DISPLAY 'city      : [' CITY ']'
           DISPLAY 'state     : [' ST ']'
           DISPLAY 'zip code  : [' ZIP ']'
           DISPLAY 'department: [' DEPT ']'
           DISPLAY 'payrate   : [' PAYRATE ']'
           DISPLAY 'commission: [' COM ']'
           DISPLAY 'misc      : [' MISCDATA-TEXT ']'
           DISPLAY 'misc (len): [' MISCDATA-LEN ']'
           
           IF COM-NULL-IND < 0 
               DISPLAY 'commission is null' 
           ELSE 
               DISPLAY 'commission ' DISP-COM 
           END-IF 
      *     DISPLAY 'Do you want to see the next record? (y/n)' 
      *     ACCEPT ANSS 
      *     IF ANSS = 'Y' OR 'y' 
               EXEC SQL 
                 FETCH EMPTBL INTO 
                   :ENO,:LNAME,:FNAME,:STREET,:CITY, 
                   :ST,:ZIP,:DEPT,:PAYRATE, 
                   :COM,:MISCDATA
               END-EXEC 
      *     ELSE 
      *         GO TO CLOSE-LOOP 
      *     END-IF 
           MOVE SQLCODE TO DISP-CODE 
           DISPLAY 'fetch ' DISP-CODE 
           DISPLAY 'fetch ' SQLCODE 
           END-PERFORM  
       
           DISPLAY 'All records in this table have been selected'. 
       
       CLOSE-LOOP.
      *  close the cursor 
           EXEC SQL 
               CLOSE EMPTBL 
           END-EXEC. 
       
       100-EXIT. 
             STOP RUN.
```

Comment: Note: the gixsql repository is at https://github.com/mridoni/gixsql, in any case - wouldn't it be most reasonable to ask there, first?

Comment: Your question is _nearly_ good, it just misses the original code, so we can't know if the issue is there or in the conversion. Please edit that in and drop a note in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't want to raise an issue on github because I figured I was doing something incorrectly, even though I am just using the examples for the moment.

Comment: This may be the answer. I was using gixsql command to precompile. When using this command there seem to be issues with the generated files. I tried a bunch of the other examples and they all had similar problems. Changing to the recommented gixpp command works.

Comment: If the gixsql command does not work the way "the recommended gixpp commands do", then please create an issue in the github issue tracker reporting this with the necessary context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With our Enterprise COBOL compiler I would expect a message along the lines of "A PERIOD WAS REQUIRED" - before starting a new section you have to end the previous sentence with a period `.`.
So try adding a period before `GIX-SKIP-CRSR-INIT.`:

```
GIXSQL GIXSQL-CI-P-TEST001-EMPTBL.
GIXSQL     CALL STATIC "GIXSQLCursorDeclare" USING
GIXSQL         BY REFERENCE SQLCA
GIXSQL         BY REFERENCE x"00"
GIXSQL         BY VALUE 0
GIXSQL         BY REFERENCE "TEST001_EMPTBL" & x"00"
GIXSQL         BY VALUE 0
GIXSQL         BY REFERENCE SQ0001
GIXSQL         BY VALUE 0
GIXSQL     END-CALL
           .
GIXSQL GIX-SKIP-CRSR-INIT.
```

But don't ask me why it isn't generated by your tool...

Comment: Thank you! This helped to narrow it down.

Comment: @dreamwagon: not sure, but it sounds like this "answer worked for you" - then please mark it as accepted answer (or write another on your own if it only "helped" to find it, and accept that)

Comment: This is the correct answer, although the cause of the issue was the precompiler not generating good COBOL source. In any case, I have marked this as the answer.